# JUnit, IntegrationTest and Test Execution Order

Tags: junit, junit5

Junit is a framework for unit testing but it is also used for integration testing. The behaviour required for unit testing and integration tests are different. Unit tests are supposed to be isolated from other tests. But integration tests require interaction between consecutive tests. In my case sceanario is as follows. Each line requires the object from the previous execution. To achieve this behaviour there should be an execution order of tests. There is an @Order annotation but this annotation orders the methods of a single class. But in my case it is not proper to keep these test in a single class.

- Create a customer
- Create a hierarchical billing account for this customer
- Create a contract for the customer
- Sell some hierarchical item for customer
- Sell some non-hierarchical item for customer

A proposal may be to make these operations for each test. For example to create a hierarchical billing account, create a customer first in the test. This scheme is not an optimum solution, has complexities too.

- Would increase required run time.
- Would increase complexity for a single test.

So is there a way for me to order my tests in Junit that I am missing? If not why it is not? Should I use another tool?

Comment: I still wouldn't have tests reuse / depend on each other. It makes for unmaintainable code. Move common code to shared methods (e.g., logging in, create fake account). Test that of course, but maybe only at the unit level. Then your test setup can create accounts as needed, and tests can work with them and still be independent of each other and test order. JUnit is a cool tool for this, and you don't have to learn a new tool if you're already running other tests in JUnit.

Comment: @Robert, for integration purposes I should have all data as real. I am not making any mock customers or mock accounts, they are like the real ones. And moving to a common method is not an option I would like. It will increase run time and increase code complexity. I should make a method that should create a customer, create an account, create a contract, sell a hierarchical product just to sell a non hierarchical product. In my scheme I could just grab the bill account and go for sale since all these steps are executed previously.